# Managing properties in web app

Tags: gui-design, web-app

I have an MFC Windows application and I'm doing some research to see whether the software can be ported to a web app.  Currently the MFC app uses quite a few CPropertySheet / CPropertyPage (also known as tab dialog boxes) windows to manage properties.  What would be the best way to present these properties to the user in a browser?

A little more info - the app is a canvas-based editor, and properties windows are often displayed when the user double-clicks on a canvas object. But there are other cases when properties for non-visual components need to be displayed and updated as well (e.g. if/when the user selects an item displayed in a list).

Comment: Hi @Kevin, can you give specific examples of what UX challenges you are experiencing with your transition?  Without examples, specifics and context it would be problematic to answer "How do a translate a Windows' tabbed dialog box to the web?"  There are simply too many possibilities.

Comment: Hi ECM, I'm just getting started, so I guess my most basic question is whether I can/should continue to use pop-up windows in the browser?  Or should I plan to move all properties into a dynamically-updated accordion-style sidebar (see http://www.divshot.com for an example).  Sorry for being a little vague, I'm still trying to get my head around this.

Comment: Do you need the property pages to be modal i.e "bring them up, make changes, click OK"? Or are they more like floating windows for info and properties?

Answer (score 1):

1. I would advise you not to "port", but to migrate or rewrite.  What I mean is the MFC desktop app's paradigm is different than a web app's.  Your main goal should be giving the end-user a simple, usable app.  Not a one-for-one replacement of your MFC controls.
2. Take a look at modern web apps, such as:
   [Windows 8 MyCompany demo applications [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - .NET 4.5.1]](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/MyCompany-demo-applications-eedab900) and 
   [DevExpress ASP.NET Demos](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/MVC/demos.xml).  Also search for "Beautiful HTML5 Apps".
3. You might want a SPA (Single Page App).  Or maybe AngularJS.  The look-and-feel, layout, navigation, etc. all depend on your end-users and what they need to do.
4. Properties are oftentimes shown in panels using progressive disclosures (accordions).  The panels can be stationary or slide-ins.